# Get custom parameter inside AppKernel

Tags: symfony, vagrant

I'm trying to include custom values for the cache and logs directories. The reason is to make it work fast with Vagrant.
This is the cache method with a static value (inside `app/AppKernel.php`):

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    if (in_array($this->environment, array('dev', 'test'))) {
        return '/dev/shm/project/app/cache/' .  $this->environment;
    }

    return parent::getCacheDir();
}
```

and I'd want to do something like:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    if (in_array($this->environment, array('dev', 'test'))) {
        return $this->getContainer()->getParameter('cache_dir') .  $this->environment;
    }

    return parent::getCacheDir();
}
```

and then, in `parameters.yml`:

```
 cache_dir: '/dev/shm/project/app/cache/'
```

But `$this->getContainer()` is returning null here. I've tried to get the container inside other kernel methods without success. Any idea if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could always try to define the class that allows you to get the cache directory as a service and then pass the service container into that class.

```
services:
  your_cache_dir_service:
      class: Acme\TestBundle\Services\CacheHelper
          arguments: [@service_container]
```

Comment: AppKernel as a service?